# How to check parent when all children checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a rather different HTML structure to other questions similar to this on SO. I want to make the parent checkbox checked when all children checkboxes are checked. I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9q4Lyam/3/) where I have added my rather long HTML code. What am I doing wrong in the Jquery? This is my jquery:

```
$('li :checkbox').on('click', function() {
      var $chk = $(this),
        $container = $chk.closest('td,li');
      if (!$container.hasClass('list-group-item')) {
        $container.find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked)
      }
      do{
        $ul = $container.parent();
        $parent = $ul.siblings(':checkbox');
        if($chk.is(':checked')){
            $parent.prop('checked', $ul.has(':checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0)
        } else {
            $parent.prop('checked', false)
        }
        $chk = $parent;
        $container = $chk.closest('td,li');
    } while($ul.is(':not(.someclass)'));
    });
```

PS: The parent/child relationship in the bottom half of the HTML structure don't work well coz of some unclosed tags. But the first few parent/children are working

Answer (score 1):

The example below should help you understand and give you a way to accomplish what you want.

**Explanation**

What you should do is give each sub-category an ID which can be used to iterate through the children so the only those checkboxes can be checked and not all of them.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test-main"> test
  </li>
  <ul id="test-sub-items">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox"> test
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox"> Something
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox"> Another Thing</li>
  </ul>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox"> Blah
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox"> blah
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var parent = document.getElementById('test-sub-items'),
  parentCheckbox = document.getElementById('test-main');

parentCheckbox.addEventListener('click', function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
    if (parentCheckbox.checked == true)
      parent.children[i].firstElementChild.checked = true;
    else
      parent.children[i].firstElementChild.checked = false;

  }
});
```

This is simply an example for you to try and incorporate in to your code.

**Update**

After reading your comment I quickly came up with this function which should help:

```
function areAllChecked() 
{
  for (var i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
    if (parentCheckbox.checked == false)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Check the console in the live example for the updated version.

**Live Example**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkwcfs2z/)

[JSFiddle (Update 1)](https://jsfiddle.net/zkwcfs2z/2/)

**Reading Material**

[`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)

[`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild)

Comment: In your fiddle, what I want does not happen. In the code I have (check the fiddle too), if a parent is checked the children get checked too. That's fine. I want to check the parent if all it's children are checked

Comment: no mate, not what I want. I want to check the parent, if all the children are checked. For example, ONE is the parent (ul). TWO and THREE (listitems) are the children. So if TWO and THREE are checked, ONE should be checked. I have gotten close, but can't get it working. This is what I'm working with now https://jsfiddle.net/YohanBlake/vwnahjj0/

Answer (score 0):

Because i did not find a way any where else i tried with trial and error on the example of @Script47
And got it to work with that:

```js
        var child = document.getElementById('test-sub-items'), parentCheckbox = document.getElementById('test-main');

    child.addEventListener('click', function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < child.children.length; i++) {
        if (child.children[i].firstElementChild.checked == true)
          parentCheckbox.checked = true;
        else
          parentCheckbox.checked = false;

      }
    });
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" id="test-main"> Essen
</li>
    <ul id="test-sub-items">
      <li><input type="checkbox"> Apfel</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"> Birne </li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"> Cadmium</li>
    </ul>

<li><input type="checkbox">Bier</li>
<li><input type="checkbox">C hohes</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This HTML is invalid. An unordered list can't be a direct descendent of another unordered list.